# zoom with taps on scrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

i am trying to remake (mostly) the same sample example provided by apple which is called **tapToZoom**.

the difference is that i am using storyboard instead of a classic nib file as the example shows, i set an image inside the scrollView.

the problem is that the zoom don't work e.g. here:

```
//set the initial zoom scale
 float minimumScale = [myScroll frame].size.width  / [myImage frame].size.width;

NSLog(@"%f",minimumScale);

[myScroll setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
[myScroll setZoomScale:minimumScale];

NSLog()@"%f",[myScroll zoomScale];
```

the logs return `0.6` for the first one and `1.0` for the second which is supposed to be `0.6`.
anyone got this problem before?

[EDIT]: the previous lines are into my viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should implement

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Try this delegate method.